# Get Bitcoin data issue

Tags: python, bitcoin

I was using below code to collect bitcoin data:

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-  
import os
import re
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

first_date = datetime.datetime(2010,7,16)


def parse_record(record):
    new_date = record[1:23]
    date = datetime.datetime(int(record[11:15]), int(record[16:18]), int(record[19:21]))
    value = record[24:-1]
    # print(record1[11:15])
    #         return [date,value]
    # translation = {39: None}
    # return str([date,value]).translate(translation)
    if date > first_date:
        return str([new_date,value]).translate(str.maketrans({"'":None}))
    
translation = {39: None} 

url_price = 'https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-price.html#alltime'


response_price = requests.get(url_price)
soup_price = BeautifulSoup(response_price.text,'lxml')

script_tag_price = soup_price.findAll('script')[4]
script_text_price = script_tag_price.text


pattern_price = re.compile(r'\[new Date\("\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}"\),\d*\.?\w*\]')
records_price = pattern_price.findall(script_text_price)




price = []

for record in records_price:
    price.append(parse_record(record))

text_file = open("btc-price.txt", "w")
text_file.write(str(price).replace("None,","")[1:-1].translate(translation).translate(str.maketrans({" ":None})).replace("newDate", "new Date"))
text_file.close()
```

One year ago it was working ok that I can get the price info in txt. But now it cannot work, it seems that the website page somehow is changed that the code cannot work again, I am new to code, anyone can help me?

Comment: @chitown88 can you help me?

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. What is the issue or error you get exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ur code is too complicated for such a simple task, u did not indicate in what format the result should be saved, I ll give an example of just the output with pandas. But full dict in **result** variable

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import datetime


response = requests.get('https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-price.html#alltime')
result = [{'Date': str(datetime.strptime(str(x.split(',')[0]), '"%Y/%m/%d")').date()),
           'Value': x.split(',')[1]} for x in re.findall(r'"\d+\/\d+\/\d+"\),\d+', response.text)]
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
            Date  Value
0     2010-07-17      0
1     2010-07-18      0
2     2010-07-19      0
3     2010-07-20      0
4     2010-07-21      0
...          ...    ...
4845  2023-10-22  29916
4846  2023-10-23  30877
4847  2023-10-24  34086
4848  2023-10-25  34329
4849  2023-10-26  34259
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing, I don't much about coding, it is working, the 'result' is like below: [{'Date': '2010-07-17', 'Value': '0'}, {'Date': '2010-07-18', 'Value': '0'}...], what can I do if I want the 'result' to be like: [new Date("2010/07/17"),0.0495],[new Date("2010/07/18"),0.0726],[new Date("2010/07/19"),0.0859] ...

Thanks.

Comment: @Marcfly7 May I know what this is for? maybe this can be solved more conveniently

Comment: I used the data like this https://github.com/marcfly7/bitcoin-bubble-index/blob/master/original_data/price.txt to generate data like this: https://github.com/marcfly7/bitcoin-bubble-index/blob/master/data.json so that I could use html file like https://github.com/marcfly7/bitcoin-bubble-index/blob/master/index.html to analyze bitcoin future.  you can see all info from https://github.com/aksnzhy/bitcoin-bubble-index

Comment: Actually I don't know how to use python, only know use the codes provided by other ppl to run.

Comment: Based on the data, I made a html years ago like this site: https://jz66k-eqaaa-aaaai-aalxq-cai.ic0.app/ 


Comment: But now I found that the site somehow changed and once it changed, I don't know how to change so that the codes could run since I don't fully understand the python codes.

Comment: @Marcfly7 just replace line to `result = [x for x in re.findall(r'\[new Date\("\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}"\),\d*\.?\w*\]', response.text)]`

Comment: It's amazing, it is working now, I want to learn python the whole code is as below: 

import pandas as pd
import requests
import datetime
import re

translation = {39: None} 

response = requests.get('https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-price.html#alltime')
result = [x for x in re.findall(r'\[new Date\("\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}"\),\d*\.?\w*\]', response.text)]


text_file = open("btc-price.txt", "w")
text_file.write(str(result).replace("None,","")[1:-1].translate(translation))
text_file.close()
Thank you very much!